# Pinch zoom & sensitivity with AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I've been using ACE for a few months now and I'm very happy with it.
I successfully tested my app on a few devices (Galaxy S2, S3, S4, Galaxy Tab2), but I've got an issue with pinch zoom on Motorola ET1. Pinch zoom is working, but not well. Sensitivity seems too low and it is very difficult to zoom in. At first I thought the problem was with the hardware (this is a rugged tablet and the screen is not as good as with phones). However when I use the built-in gallery app, pinch zoom is working fine. So this really has to deal with ACE. I tried looking into TouchHandler.java, with no luck. I'm using only line plot with approximately 500 points.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it working better with 50 points only? Does pan work well?

Comment: Pan is working perfectly well! I'll try with 50 pts and let you know...

Comment: Dan, I tried with 50 pts only: yes, it is better, no doubt, but still not so good as with my phone...